C# project created in CLI with custom template returns empty folder
I've set up a template for a microservice that we will have to create plenty of in an upcoming project. After following all the steps, I was able to create a nupkg package. I've installed the template but it only generates an empty folder. All the output returns successfully, so I'm fresh out of ideas.
Here's my template.json file:
    {
      "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
      "author": "ME",
      "classifications": ["WebAPI", "Microservice"],
      "identity": "MicroService.Template",
      "name": "MicroserviceTemplate",
      "shortName": "microservice",
      "sourceName": "MicroserviceTemplate",
      "preferNameDirectory": true,
      "tags": {
        "language": "C#",
        "type": "project"
      },
  "symbols": {
    "PROJECT_NAME": {
      "type": "parameter",
      "defaultValue": "MyMicroService",
      "replaces": "MyMicroService"
    }
  },
      "primaryOutputs": [
      { "path": "MicroServiceTemplate.sln" },
      { "path": "MyMicroService.API/MyMicroService.API.csproj" },
      { "path": "MyMicroService.Events/MyMicroService.Events.csproj" },
      { "path": "MyMicroService.Domain/MyMicroService.Domain.csproj" },
      { "path": "MyMicroService.DataAccess/MyMicroService.DataAccess.csproj" },
      { "path": "MyMicroService.Contracts/MyMicroService.Contracts.csproj" },
      { "path": "MyMicroService.API.Tests/MyMicroService.API.Tests.csproj" },
      { "path": "MyMicroService.Events.Tests/MyMicroService.Events.Tests.csproj" },
      { "path": "MyMicroService.Domain.Tests/MyMicroService.Domain.Tests.csproj" },
      { "path": "MyMicroService.DataAccess.Tests/MyMicroService.DataAccess.Tests.csproj" }
        ]
    }

The MicroService.Template.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <PackageId>MicroService.Template</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>Me</Authors>
    <Description>A template for microservices</Description>
    <PackageTags>template;microservice</PackageTags>
    <OutputPath>./nupkg</OutputPath>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
    <IncludeSource>true</IncludeSource>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>   
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include=".template.config/**" Pack="true" PackagePath="content/.template.config/" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <!-- Include other necessary files -->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

And an example of one of the csproj files from one project in the solution:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <RootNamespace>{{PROJECT_NAME}}.API</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>{{PROJECT_NAME}}.API</AssemblyName>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>    
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.OpenApi" Version="1.6.17" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.7.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\MyMicroService.Contracts\MyMicroService.Contracts.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\MyMicroService.Domain\MyMicroService.Domain.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Might it have something to do with the {{placeholders}} I've put in the project names in the csproj files? But then I would think atleast the sln file should be created.

After my test, I did not encounter your situation. The corresponding files should be generated in the end. I would like to know how you created the project. I used manual creation or the command: dotnet new microservice -n myproject

@CodyLiang I also use dotnet new microservice -name something. And the placeholders were changed correctly ?

The template also shows up in Rider, but with the same result. Did you also use dotnet pack MicroService.Template.csproj to create the nupkg ?

I wonder if you want to use a template to create a project or what? Could you provide me with a general step of how you did it so I can try to reproduce the issue? Also, I don't see a description of placeholders in the information you provided, please provide a description of that as well.

@CodyLiang I'm trying to set up a template for microservices that my team will be creating soon, so that we all use the same project structure. The placeholders can be seen in the RootNameSpace of the PropertyGroup of each csproj file of each project in the solution. I did 'dotnet pack MicroService.Template.csproj -> dotnet install 'the nupkg package' -> the template shows up when I type dotnet new --list -> dotnet new microservice -n 'whateverprojectname' -> empty folder. Is there anything else you'd want to know ?

I used the same steps and commands as you, but the same problem still does not occur. Could you please try creating a simple template to test if this is still happening.

@CodyLiang I created a webapi project from template and noticed that it does a dotnet restore to read the csproj files, something that my custom microservice template does not do. You created the template based on my config files and it does work ? The MicroService.Template.csproj file is in the same folder as all the other project folders and the sln folder, together with the .template/config folder.

@CodyLiang I changed my .nupkg to a .zip file so I could see what it contains, and the csproj files aren't present. I'd assume this means that something is going wrong with the packaging.
